# Issues with Pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I have some issues with the use of the Pipeline Tool and the GridSearchCV.
I get the following error message: "TypeError: Last step of Pipeline should implement fit or be the string 'passthrough'. '1' (type ) doesn't".

Do you see where is my mistake here?

Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


X = wage['age'][:, np.newaxis]
y = wage['wage'][:, np.newaxis]

degree = 2
model = Pipeline(steps=[('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree)), ('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))])

param_grid = {'poly': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
cv_model = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring='r2', cv=5, n_jobs=1)
cv_model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the problem comes from the fact that I didn't use the '__' notation after the 'poly' in the param_grid.

With this notation, it seems to work:

```
param_grid = {'poly__degree': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```